# Sent money from Bitcoin Core to mobile Electrum and for 3 days can`t recieve it

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain, wallet, electrum

3 days ago I made transaction from my Bitcoin Core to my mobile Electrum but I didn't receive any money yet. I can't see this transaction in Electrum and on Blockain,Tradeblock either, however, Bitcoin Core shows that the money are sent. Usually I can see my transactions in Blockchain and Electrum but that doesn`t work with that transaction at all. There is definitely a problem with the app Bitcoin Core.

Who knows how I can receive money?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Does the explorer says "unconfirmed"?